# Constructing do while loop to handle account numbers not working C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a do while loop to evaluate account numbers. A valid account number has to have 5 digits and start with the letters R or B, not case sensitive.

Valid account number examples:
r90000
B10101
R88888
b77777

invalid account number examples:
y90000
r888822

This is the loop I've made, and I can't figure out what's wrong with my parameters that's causing it to repeat over and over again, never excepting an account number.

```
char accountType;
int accountNum;

cout << "Please enter your account number." <<endl;
cout << ">> ";
cin >> accountType >> accountNum;
cout <<endl;

do 
{
    cout << "That is not a valid account number. Please enter your account number." <<endl;
    cout << ">> ";
    cin >> accountType >> accountNum;
    cout <<endl;
}while ( (accountNum <= 9999) || (accountNum >= 100000) && (accountType != 'r') || (accountType != 'R') || (accountType != 'b') || (accountType != 'B') );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also the point of a **do...while** loop is to avoid repeating blocks of code, like you have.  Less code ---> less debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions for repeating the loop are **any** of:

1. `accountNum  <= 9999`
2. `accountNum >= 100000 && accountType != 'r'`
3. `accountType != 'R'`
4. `accountType != 'b'`
5. `accountType != 'B'`

But for **every** character, at least two of (3), (4), and (5) are true, so you'll always repeat.

You need to loop while **all** of the `accountType` checks fail OR any of the `accountNum` checks fail. That is, any of:

1. `accountNum  <= 9999`
2. `accountNum >= 100000`
3. `accountType != 'r' && accountType != 'R' && accountType != 'b' && accountType != 'B'`

Comment: Are you saying I need to create separate loops for checking the account number and the account type?

Comment: No, he's not saying that. He's saying your end condition is wrong, you have to replace `||` by `&&` in some cases and certainly add parenthesis would help.